# Grouping rows aggregate and function in r part II

Tags: r, database, function, aggregate

Asked a similar question before and it was answered exceptionally in detail.

[Grouping rows aggregate and function in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64762654/grouping-rows-aggregate-and-function-in-r)

My new grouping function is the pooled variance. **I have attached a picture and link of the formula**.

Pooled variance to be used ([link to formula](https://stats.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Applied_Statistics/Book%3A_An_Introduction_to_Psychological_Statistics_(Foster_et_al.)/10%3A__Independent_Samples/10.05%3A_Standard_Error_and_Pooled_Variance))

[image: picture of formula]

The way it works is as follows we can only use the formula to combine two rows at a time until we are left with 1 row entry.

```
combined s value = sqrt (   ((n1 - 1) * (s1)^2  +  (n2 - 1) * (s2)^2)   /    ( n1 + n2 -2 ) )
```

where n1 and n2 are the population sizes

**Note:** Every time we combine a group of two the n value changes to n1 + n2

```
  data to be used 
          k  n    s
        1 g 10   2.5
        2 g 10   4.2
        3 g 10   3.1
        4 r 10   5.0
        5 r 10   3.8
        6 r 10   2.7
    
    expected results 
    
          k   n     s          
        1 g   30    3.3458   
        2 r   30    3.9654    
    
    Operation Logic:     
    
    combining (k = g)             
                             
        k   n      s               
    1   g   10    2.5
    2   g   10    4.2               
    3   g   10    3.1
     
    combining row 1 & 2 
          k   n      s  
    1"2   g   20   3.45615 
    3     g   10   3.1       
     
    combining row 1"2 & 3 
            k   n      s  
    1"2"3   g   30   3.3458
    
    combining (k = r) 
        
        k   n     s               
    4   r   10    5
    5   r   10    3.8              
    6   r   10    2.7
     
    combining row 4 & 5 
          k   n      s  
    4"5   r   20   4.4407 
    6     r   10   2.7       
     
    combining row 4"5 & 6 
            k   n      s  
    4"5"6   g   30   3.9654
```

Comment: Are you sure that your operation logic is correct? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pooled_variance) tells me that even for more than three groups, the pooled variance is just a weighted average of their variances. That textbook also admits that "... [the pooled variance] is in fact just a weighted average".

Comment: I don't think it's the same http://statstodo.com/CombineMeansSDs_Pgm.php

Comment: So you actually want Cochrane's approach? Then the formula is different from the one you showed above. @FalconX

Comment: It turns out that the Wikipedia post you sent would be appropriate for independent runs and it's not necessary to do it like this.  Thanks